# About the installation of micro-framework Silex

Tags: php, eclipse, silex

I will modify a project already developped with PHP and micro-Framework Silex.
I installed the IDE Eclipse for PHP developper. Should I install Silex also knowing that all the dependencie exists in the project ?

Thank you.

Comment: If it has a composer.json file, install composer and run `composer install`.

Comment: And if it _doesn't_ have a `composer.json` file (and `composer.lock`) you probably want to figure out why and then create an appropriate one.

Comment: it has the two files composer.json and composer.lock. I tried to install composer but in the step it require a php.exe, i can't know which file php.exe I should browse it.

Comment: I tried to install it also the Twig from Eclipse Marketplace but it display this error No repository found at http://p2.pdt-extensions.org/.

Comment: You do have a [PHP installation](http://windows.php.net/download/) (or you could use WAMP/XAMP/etc.), do you? (you should have the same version as the production server your application is running)

Comment: In fact, i will modifiy online the project, it's on the server of the company. So i don't installed any Apache, server... just Eclipse for PHP developper. And all the dependencies into the project (Silex, Composer).

Comment: You should not touch production code at all! You should have a local development environment and make changes locally, when your changes are done you should depoly them to the production server. Also you cannot run composer if you don't have a php executable on your machine.

Comment: Good idea thank you, i'll suggest to my manager..